# Multiple times same node and same topics

Tags: ros-noetic, node, topic

In ROS1 Noetic my students like to launch multiple times:

- the same node;
- the same topics.

What is the exact effect of these multiple declarations ?

For Node, is-it a problem ?

When you create multiple times the same Publisher, how the system deals with this ? Each time you create a publisher, you reserve some space in memory, you define a new port and you give information to ROSMASTER.

For topics if you define multiple times the same Subscriber, each object can receive the data and use their own callback function ?

Thanks

Goupil

===========================
Example of student's work using class:

class TurtleBotController:

```
def __init__(self):

    rospy.init_node('turtlebot_controller')

    self.pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)

    self.scan_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber('/scan', LaserScan, self.lidar_callback)
```

...

if **name** == '**main**':

```
controller = TurtleBotController()

controller2 = TurtleBotController()
```

...

Answer (score 0):

> If you define multiple Subscribers, can each subscriber receive the data and use their own callback function?

Yes, just be aware to namespace the node (with the callback function) so there are no duplicates node names, which may cause some issues and wouldn't be able to see it in the `rqt` node graph.

You can also run `rostopic info <topic>` after all the launching to see how many publishers and describers are on that topic. More commands [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic).